# Изменение bool свойства с помощью кнопки

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем, можно ли с помощью кнопки изменять bool свойство дважды? Нажал на кнопку свойство переключилось в состояние true, отпустил кнопку состояние переключилось в false

Например:

Есть свойство

```
 @State var isOn: Bool = false

Button(action: {
     isOn.toggle()
    }) {
    Text("Tap Me!)
    }
```

Данный метод не сработает, чтобы переключить в состояние true и обратно, нужно нажать кнопку 2 раза.

Comment: посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/57864639/3004003

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов решения проблемы, который я смог найти:

```
Button(action: {
         isOn = true
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                    isOn = false
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
```

при нажатии на кнопку произойдет переключение в true, после этого через 0.2 секунды (оптимальное время, по моему мнению, чтобы переключение произошло незаметно) переменная будет переключена в состояние false